# Why does exp(log(6)) == exp(log(3)) * 2 return FALSE in R?

Tags: r, precision, double-precision

In R, why is this false for y > 2?

```
y <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
x <- 2*y
exp(log(x)) == exp(log(y)) * 2
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Floating point roundoff error. You'll notice that `exp(log(y))` is not exactly `3`. Have a read of [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Thank you. In this case I know from theory that the results must be the same. How do I compare results in a case where I don't know if they should be equal? Impossible?

Comment: But `exp(log(y))` returns `[1] 1 2 3 4 5`, and `exp(log(x))` returns `[1]  2  4  6  8 10` which is exactly what was confusing me.

Comment: Use `sprintf("%.20f", exp(log(y)))` to get it displayed with more precision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numeric precision. Try calculating the difference:

```
exp(log(x)) - exp(log(y)) * 2
```

You could use something like:

```
all.equal( exp(log(x)) , exp(log(y)) * 2 )
```

Comment: Or something like `apply(cbind(exp(log(x)), exp(log(y)) * 2), 1, function(tmp) all.equal(tmp[[1]],tmp[[2]]))` to check each element.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, the numerci precision is the cause. Try this, even simpler calculation

```
1/2+1/3+1/6 #equal to 1    
(1/2+1/3+1/6)-1 # should be 0
[1] -1.110223e-16
```

Comment: The first row displays `1`, but it is not ''equal to 1''.